Why does scanf take two inputs when running this code?
When using the scanf function to take an input, two inputs are given.
For starters, I am a python programmer trying to learn C. I tried to search why this was happening but found nothing. Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int age;

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &age);
    printf("Your age is %d\n", age);
    
    return 0;
}

When running and debugging in VSCode, this is what I get:
Enter your age: 23
12
Your age is 23

Any help would be appreciated.

What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?

As a rule, never use scanf for line-based input. Instead, use getline followed by sscanf within the resulting string. If your compiler still lacks getline, it's trivial to implement as a wrapper around an fgets loop.

@o11c " If your compiler still lacks getline, it's trivial to implement as a wrapper around an fgets loop" --> Trivial? Depends if you want to also want to read null characters or long lines.

The \n is unnecessary in the scanf format string. It tells scanf to continue reading any number of whitespace characters, until it finds the next non-whitespace character.
Instead, just use scanf("%d", &age);

"Unnecessary" is a polite way of saying "a horrid user experience trap for the unwary".  For all practical purposes, ending a scanf() format string with white space is always a bug.  (The limited exception requires the input to come from a file so that humans are not involved in guessing what the next input should be (because you have to start typing the next input before the scanf() with trailing white space in the format string will terminate).  And even then, it is not necessary, nor even desirable — it might be tolerated, that's all, but it's a bad idea.)
